# С помощью чего можно считать первую текстовую строку из файла .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть файл .txt где написано "Один" "Два", есть второй файл .txt где написано "1" "2" (Написано это строчками то есть после "Один" ставиться Enter, как и c "1", думаю понятно ). Мне нужно брать первую строчку из обоих файлов и кинуть в массив. Я это делал с помощью `.readline()`, но получилось так что, с первым файлом, где находиться текст, возникают проблемы, текст превращается в непонятный набор символов. Как я понял `.readline()` работает только с цифрами, с помощью чего можно так же работать с текстом. Спасибо.

```
with open ('R2.txt' ) as f:
    name = f.readline()
with open ('R1.txt') as f2:
    number = f2.readline()
```

Comment: Укажите кодировку файла, скорее всего вы ее не указывали и использовалась системная (а у файла другая кодировка), поэтому получили кракозябры, а `.readline()` работает с символами, а не только с цифрами. Попробуйте указывать `encoding="utf-8"` в `open`

Comment: я обновил вопрос, и не могу понять где указать

Comment: В ответе уже есть подсказка, просто сравните ваш код и автора ответа, добавив мое замечание. Плюс, вы могли посмотреть в спеку про метод `open`. А так, пример считывания файла в `utf-8`: `with open('R1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Comment: Большое спасибо :) проблема была в том что я указывал кодировку сразу после open.